# Notation for Percentile Range of Sample

Tags: sampling, quantiles, notation

Let $X$ be a random variable with unknown CDF $F_X$ and PDF $f_X$. What is the notation for a percentile range $[0,p]$ on a sample of $X$ that allows discussing sample statistics over that range? My attempt:

$$
\begin{aligned}
s &= \{x\ |\ x \in X,\ x < F_X^{-1}(p)\} \\
\bar{s} &= \text{mean of $s$} \\
\mu_s &= \text{mean of $s$} \\
\sigma_s &= \text{standard deviation of $s$}
\end{aligned}
$$

Shortcomings:

- Set notation precludes the possibility of duplicate draws
- $x \in X$ implies $X$ is a set, which it is not. Similarly $x \sim f_X(x)$ implies $x$ is a random variable, which it is not.
- The statement is meaningless because $F_X$ is unknown and because the percentile range of $F_X$ may differ from the percentile range of the sample.

Comment: A standard notation related to $X$ is $F^{-1}([0,p]).$  However, your question does not distinguish the distribution $F_X$ from the *empirical distribution of the sample.*  Which one are you trying to ask about?  What exactly do you mean by "percentile range ... on a sample of $X$"?

Comment: I've often seen ranges similar in spirit to interquartile ranges. Even there it's up in the air whether the range means two values defining an interval or the difference between them (the length of the interval). SImilarly, you might have the difference between the 1% and 99% or 5 and 95% points, or indeed there is no reason why one would always have $p$ and $1 - p$ as associated cumulative probabilities. I have always managed to avoid the question of notation, if only because there might be reason to look at percentiles for percents or probabilities that were awkward numbers.

Comment: I'm interested in the empirical distribution of the single sample. I'm not asking about the distribution $F_X$ though I would be interested in learning more about percentile filter functions on random variables, $X \rightarrow Y$. I'm not interested in the sampling distribution of a given statistic across multiple samples. By percentile range on a sample, I mean all the values that are less than the nearest percentile rank, i.e. as an order statistic sequence on sample $s$: $\left[ s_{(1)},\ \ldots,\ s_{(\lceil \frac{p}{100} |s| \rceil)} \right]$.

Comment: This question remains extremely confusing.  It now looks like there's no need to refer to any underlying distribution: you have a bunch of numbers and you wish to describe the lowest $100p$ percent of them.  That much seems evident, based on your comments.  But what do you mean by "sample statistics over that range"?  Maybe you wish to *truncate* a sample?

Comment: Yes, a truncation.